# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. Getting my site to display

Tags: web, iis

I am trying to change the content of my site (it is a help site and I have gone from using one software package to another for creating it) and usually, I would just make sure that the content was in the root folder and all is good.

The issue is that when I change the content I get a 404 error, so I did some googling and put some code in the web.config file and now I get a 403 error! Then I tried everything I could and still get the 403.

If I change the content in the root folder back to the original, there is no problem and on another site I have, I can just add a folder then navigate to [www.site.com/newfolder](http://www.site.com/newfolder) and it works fine.

Comment: Learn the status code (and more importantly the substatus code) and what really they mean, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code then you might help yourself out.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I find out what the sub status is?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show what you did when the error was 404? You can get sub status code in development mode of browser, or check the log of IIS. The log file is in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles.

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue, can you show the sub status code of 404 and error message?